# Longtable caption

Tags: longtable

I have this longtable and the caption is not appearing in the first part of the table

```
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
\caption{Tipo N} \label{tab:Uh_B Ip y t ctes} \\
$U_h$    & $\Delta U_h$   & $B [T]$ & $\Delta B [T]$ \\ \hline\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$U_h$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\Delta U_h$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$B [T]$ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta B [T]$} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continuación}} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$U_h$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\Delta U_h$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$B [T]$ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta B [T]$} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{{Continua en la siguiente página}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

0,054  & 0,001 & -0,300    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,05   & 0,001 & -0,280    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,046  & 0,001 & -0,260    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,041  & 0,001 & -0,240    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,037  & 0,001 & -0,220    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,032  & 0,001 & -0,200    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,028  & 0,001 & -0,180    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,023  & 0,001 & -0,160    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,019  & 0,001 & -0,140    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,014  & 0,001 & -0,120    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,010  & 0,001 & -0,100    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,005  & 0,001 & -0,080    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,001  & 0,001 & -0,060    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,002 & 0,001 & -0,040    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,007 & 0,001 & -0,020    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,011 & 0,001 & 0,000     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,016 & 0,001 & 0,020     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,021 & 0,001 & 0,040     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,026 & 0,001 & 0,060     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,030 & 0,001 & 0,080     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,034 & 0,001 & 0,100     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,039 & 0,001 & 0,120     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,043 & 0,001 & 0,140     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,048 & 0,001 & 0,160     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,052 & 0,001 & 0,180     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,057 & 0,001 & 0,200     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,061 & 0,001 & 0,220     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,065 & 0,001 & 0,240     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,070 & 0,001 & 0,260     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,074 & 0,001 & 0,280     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,079 & 0,001 & 0,300     & 0,001      \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

This provides the next output:

[image]

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please extend your example to a complete but minimal self contained example others can just copy and test as is. That makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: Note that you have two `\endfirsthead` commands, the latter replaces the former

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `siunitx` package in order to correctly format the data in the columns. For example the negative numbers should have a minus not a hyphen (text vs math).

Comment: @daleif That \endfirsthead was the problem thank you. I know, but there is a lot of data and it was to tedious to change all of them form de excel

Comment: That is why `siunitx` is smart, you just change the table configuration and `protect` your table headers and `siunitx does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

- Unfortunately you not provide a complete small document with your table, so the needed/used preamble is unknown.
- If I insert your code fragment into standard `article`document, I can reproduce your problem.
- However, if I retype your longtable "preamble" with table settings, I got expect result (after third compilation, as is required at long table).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
        \begin{longtable}{c c c c}
\caption{Tipo N}
\label{T2.4}    \\
$U_h$    & $\Delta U_h$   & $B [T]$ & $\Delta B [T]$ \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Tipo N --  (cont.)}             \\
$U_h$    & $\Delta U_h$   & $B [T]$ & $\Delta B [T]$ \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline\hline
\endlastfoot

0,054  & 0,001 & -0,300    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,05   & 0,001 & -0,280    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,046  & 0,001 & -0,260    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,041  & 0,001 & -0,240    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,037  & 0,001 & -0,220    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,032  & 0,001 & -0,200    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,028  & 0,001 & -0,180    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,023  & 0,001 & -0,160    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,019  & 0,001 & -0,140    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,014  & 0,001 & -0,120    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,010  & 0,001 & -0,100    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,005  & 0,001 & -0,080    & 0,001      \\ \hline
0,001  & 0,001 & -0,060    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,002 & 0,001 & -0,040    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,007 & 0,001 & -0,020    & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,011 & 0,001 & 0,000     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,016 & 0,001 & 0,020     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,021 & 0,001 & 0,040     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,026 & 0,001 & 0,060     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,030 & 0,001 & 0,080     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,034 & 0,001 & 0,100     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,039 & 0,001 & 0,120     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,043 & 0,001 & 0,140     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,048 & 0,001 & 0,160     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,052 & 0,001 & 0,180     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,057 & 0,001 & 0,200     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,061 & 0,001 & 0,220     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,065 & 0,001 & 0,240     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,070 & 0,001 & 0,260     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,074 & 0,001 & 0,280     & 0,001      \\ \hline
-0,079 & 0,001 & 0,300     & 0,001      \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I would consider @daleif comments and beside this use `tabularray`
package for your table. With them table is nicer and its code is simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
        \begin{longtblr}[    
caption = {Tipo N},
  label = {T2.4}        ]{hline{2-Z}, vline{2-Y},
                          colspec = {Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                                     Q[c, si={table-format= 1.3}]
                                     Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                                     Q[c, si={table-format= 1.3}]},
                          row{1} = {guard, mode=math},
                          rowhead=1}
U_h    & \Delta U_h   & B [T] & \Delta B [T] \\
% table body as before, but without all \hline-s
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is unclear, why you left out top, left and right table lines. I would suggest to remove all vertical and horizontal lines except necessary around column headers and bottom of table. For those lines I would use rules of `booktabs` package (loaded by `tblr` library):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Tipo N},
label = {T2.4}        ]{colspec = {Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format= 1.3}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format= 1.3}]},
                      row{1} = {guard, mode=math},
                      row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 0pt},
                      row{even[3]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead=1}
\toprule
U_h    & \Delta U_h   & B [T] & \Delta B [T] \\
\midrule
% table body is the same as before, but without all \hline-s
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like @Zarko does in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676831/5001), I suggest you employ the `siunitx` package -- and its `S` column type in particular -- to align the numbers on their respective decimal markers.

I would further get rid of all vertical rules and use fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. To provide some "visual rhythm" in the body of the long table, I'd add a bit more vertical whitespace after every fifth row or so.

And, of course, do get rid of the second `\endfirsthead` block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} *{4}{S[table-format=-1.3]} @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption{Tipo N} \label{tab:Uh_B Ip y t ctes} \\
{$U_h$} & {$\Delta U_h$} & {$B[T]$} & {$\Delta B[T]$} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- Continuación} \\[1ex]
{$U_h$} & {$\Delta U_h$} & {$B[T]$} & {$\Delta B[T]$} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule 
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Continua en la siguiente página} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule 
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

0,054  & 0,001 & -0,300    & 0,001      \\
0,05   & 0,001 & -0,280    & 0,001      \\
0,046  & 0,001 & -0,260    & 0,001      \\
0,041  & 0,001 & -0,240    & 0,001      \\
0,037  & 0,001 & -0,220    & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
0,032  & 0,001 & -0,200    & 0,001      \\
0,028  & 0,001 & -0,180    & 0,001      \\
0,023  & 0,001 & -0,160    & 0,001      \\
0,019  & 0,001 & -0,140    & 0,001      \\
0,014  & 0,001 & -0,120    & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
0,010  & 0,001 & -0,100    & 0,001      \\
0,005  & 0,001 & -0,080    & 0,001      \\
0,001  & 0,001 & -0,060    & 0,001      \\
-0,002 & 0,001 & -0,040    & 0,001      \\
-0,007 & 0,001 & -0,020    & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
-0,011 & 0,001 & 0,000     & 0,001      \\
-0,016 & 0,001 & 0,020     & 0,001      \\
-0,021 & 0,001 & 0,040     & 0,001      \\
-0,026 & 0,001 & 0,060     & 0,001      \\
-0,030 & 0,001 & 0,080     & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
-0,034 & 0,001 & 0,100     & 0,001      \\
-0,039 & 0,001 & 0,120     & 0,001      \\
-0,043 & 0,001 & 0,140     & 0,001      \\
-0,048 & 0,001 & 0,160     & 0,001      \\
-0,052 & 0,001 & 0,180     & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
-0,057 & 0,001 & 0,200     & 0,001      \\
-0,061 & 0,001 & 0,220     & 0,001      \\
-0,065 & 0,001 & 0,240     & 0,001      \\
-0,070 & 0,001 & 0,260     & 0,001      \\
-0,074 & 0,001 & 0,280     & 0,001      \\
\addlinespace
-0,079 & 0,001 & 0,300     & 0,001      \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```